# Bedeutung des Satzes: Richten Sie sich doch nur selbst aus dem Parlament

Tags: verb, separable-verb

I am an advanced german speaker but i cannot understand a phrase uttered from Herbert Wehner to Josef Strauß: Which is (in german):

> Wenn Sie das Theater so weiter führen, richten Sie sich doch nur selbst.

From this [vid](https://youtu.be/01OgjnWvpI8?t=260).

What does he mean with "... richten Sie sich doch nur selbst ..."

You can answer in German if you like.

Ein Satz vom Parlament, den ich nicht verstehen kann. Bitte um Unterstützung.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *judge* is in German *»ein Richter«.* And what a judge does in a court of law is to judge. The verb *to judge* is in German *richten:*

> Ger: Wenn Sie das Theater so weiter führen, richten Sie sich doch nur selbst.
> Eng: If you continue to act up, you are only judging yourself.

This means, that if the addressee of this message continues to behave as he does now, it will become obvious to everybody that he is doing something wrong. No judge will have to find it out because everybody can see it.

Comment: Ich bedanke mich bei Dir. Das war nicht einfach für mich zu verstehen. Beim Deutschlernen sind nur die ersten 100 Jahre schwierig. Dann wird es einfach (Spaß)

Comment: Ich weiß nicht, ob das nur mein Sprachgefühl ist, aber speziell _sich selbst richten_ aber auch _jemanden richten_ bedeutet für mich _hinrichten_, also exekutieren. Im übertragenen Sinne wäre das sich selbst untragbar für das Amt zu machen